# Optional vs Guava Optional

Tags: java, java-8, guava

I've been using `Optional` provided from `Guava` in my project for a very long time. Now I decided to migrate from Java 7 to Java 8, but since in all over my project I used `guava`'s `Optional` so far, I have to run through the code and make significant changes. Though I am not yet sure if it's worth to change, or it's better to left everything as is, and just start using Java's `Optional` from now on.

Are there any benefits or leaks in Java's `Optional`, is it better than what we have in `guava`?

Comment: IMHO, Java 8's Optional is an adaptation of Guava's Optional. That said, maybe a regex could replace all your imports.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

API of both classes is not the same. I would not change this by regexp.
Three differences which are important in my opinion:

1. Optional in Guava is abstract which means objects are subclasses. In Java Optional is final which means there are no sub classes.
2. In guava Optional is Serializable. in Java Optional is not Serializable.
3. Methods are not exactly the same.

Comment: Guavas Optional is abstract, but does not permit outside packages to subclass it.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the differences of Optional and Guava Optional?